# How to resolve a circular reference / livelock

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I seem to have myself an equation that is what MS Excel refers to as a circular reference; that I believe is also called a "Livelock".

I have composed the formula:

`A = M + D - R - (0.05(A - 250000)+2500)`

Where:

```
A = Offer Price
M = Mortgage
D = Deposit
R = Renovation costs
```

Is it even possible to resolve `A`?

#### Background

I'm trying to calculate an offer price to make on a property, based on certain costs, including Stamp Duty Land Tax (SDLT), but SDLT requires the offer price.

I'm afraid my GCSE maths was so long ago, I can't think of a way that I might achieve this, or what it might be called in mathematics (unless it's a simultaneous equation (hence tag)).

TIA.

Comment: Expand the right-hand side, move all the terms with `A` to the left side and divide through by the resulting coefficient.

Comment: Circular references of formulas are not locks of any kind. They generally just lead to simplification of formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is elementary algebra; we treat everything else as a constant and work to isolate $A$. First, we expand out that expression on the right using the distributive property:
$$ A = M+D-R - (0.05(A-250000)+2500)$$
$$ A = M+D-R - 0.05(A-250000)-2500$$
$$ A = M+D-R - 0.05A +0.05\cdot 250000-2500$$
Next, we move all the multiples of $A$ over to one side, and apply the distributive property in reverse. I'll also consolidate the constant terms here:
$$A + 0.05A = M+D-R + 12500-2500$$
$$1.05\cdot A = M+D-R + 10000$$
Finally, divide by the coefficient of $A$:
$$A = \frac1{1.05}(M+D-R + 10000)$$

Comment: Thank you @jmerry. I guess like most things in life, it's simple when you know how.